# HTML 5 + Progress element check?

Tags: javascript, html

This might be very basic, or not possible, but it's alluding me and worth asking.  Is there a way to check if the html 5 progress element is supported in a browser?

```
var progress = document.createElement('progress');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another oneliner, taken from [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/elem/progress-meter.js):

```
//returns true if progress is enabled
var supportsProgress = (document.createElement('progress').max !== undefined);
```

Comment: This is super clean and just what I wanted. I have to remember to check Modernizr... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create a `progress` element and check for the `max` attribute:

```
function progressIsSupported() {
  var test = document.createElement('progress');
  return (
      typeof test === 'object' &&
      'max' in test
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice one liner:

```
function supportsProgress() {
    return (t = document.createElement("progress")) && t.hasOwnProperty("max");
}
```

Or if you really don't want to use a global:

```
function supportsProgress() {
    var t = document.createElement("progress");
    return t && t.hasOwnProperty("max");
}
```